# ubuntu 14.04 cant connect to any development board through ethernet

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ethernet

i was trying to connect by intel galelio board to ubuntu 14.04 through ethernet but it is not getting connected. it shows "connecting" for some time (the networking symbol is blinking) and then it says ethernet connection disconnected. again it tries to connect after some time it says disconnect. this goes on. i had the same experience when i tried connecting a rapberry pi. but i can connect this boards in windows and are working good. can some1 please figure this out? thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you connecting the board to your router so that it obtains an IP by DHCP; or are you giving the boards static IPs? Is the board connected via a crossover cable directly into your computer? Or are you using a standard patch cable and the ethernet cards have automatic crossover detection?

Comment: the board has static ip . it is connected via normal Ethernet cable which i used to connect my laptop to switch. i dont know if they have crossover detection.

Comment: Does the board connect directly into your laptop, or does it connect via the ethernet switch you mention? Your comment didn't really give an immediate answer :)

Comment: sorry for being unclear. there is no switch in picture , i just mean to say its a normal ethernet cable. iam directly connecting lap to galelio